# tinyMCE upgrade

Tags: tinymce

I was wondering if there is an easy way to upgrade tinyMCE?

Or if Ebay/Magento has any plans to add a newer version to for example Magento 1.9.x.x

I came across this just today: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/wysiwyg-editor-pro-by-litextension.html and was thinkin of testing that .... (and I can't help think then - how can someone make this extension and why is this not in the core)

Answer (score 2):

At the agency I work for, we've tried a number of wysiwyg editors -- none seem to do a good job.  We generally try to avoid using the WYSIWYG editor all together and just switch to text mode.

This is one that was somewhat useful:
http://www.mgt-commerce.com/redactor-jquery-wysiwyg-for-magento.html

Comment: Such a shame. It is how we do it too. Avoid using it. But this really is a core element. And why I think Mage should have it in updates.

Comment: Text mode and Dreamweaver are a really good combination. The TinyMCE editor never has the flexibility to create really good content. It only ever has been a stopgap for shopowners who don't have html design skills.